# Firebase verify post dimensions before uploading

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

I have a Cropper component on my client side (React Native app) which lets the user to crop an image before posting it to my Firebase database. But, what about hackers? I think that if someone gets the apk and see the code, maybe will modify my Cropper and rebuild the app, breaking my bussiness rules.

So, what I want to know is if there is a mechanism to check the dimensions of a picture on the backend (firebase) and decide to post the photo or return an error message to the client.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images through a Cloud Function or Firebase Function and check it there. It is not necessary that the Function is from Firebase.

The image will be uploaded as the body in the http request, then, you load that image and check its size using a frame work https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size. If the checks are passed, you can store it where it was supposed.